# What are Up and Down functions in controllers?

Tags: model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I see use of Up and Down (aka setUp, tearDown) functions in MVC environments. What do they mean?

Comment: You mean in the unit test projects, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs some better definition, but in general these methods usually indicate that some other framework or resource is in control of the lifecycle of the object you are in.  They act as leaf methods, invoked by the framework (in the case if a JUNit test) after the test framework has created all the required plumbing and instantiated your test.  Since you don't get to create your own constructor, the framework will invoke setUp() for you.  Any code you would have normally placed in a constructor would go here. The opposite is true of teardown. You are not controlling the lifecycle of some object, but you may have created or consumed shared resources that need to be unallocated or returned before the end of the life of the object. The tearDown method is an indicator you should release resources and prepare your object to close up shop (so to speak)